# Internal pages PR

Tags: seo, pagerank

My homepage has a PR of 5. However, 99% of my internal pages have PR of 0 for some reason.
What can be the cause of it? I have a sitemap and Google Webmaster Tools shows that all my website pages are indexed.
(The internal pages are built with SEO in mind, and have several sources linking to them).

Thanks!

Joel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PR is all about links. Internal pages have fewer links then home pages because most incoming links from other sites point ot the home page and internal pages link to the home page more then other internal pages. So the homepage naturally tends to have a high PR and internal pages are lower.

If you want your internal page to have higher PR get more links to those pages from other sites and do a better job of internal inking within your site.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the pagerank you see is the so called "toolbar-pr". Google updates the pagerank of your pages much more often but only updates / exports the toolbar-pr every couple of months. So it can be that your inner pages do have a higher pagerank, but that is not yet reflected in your pagerank tool. Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank#Google_Toolbar

For the rest I agree with John Conde.